# want to change the version of firebase 8.2.10 to 7.9.0 but facing error

Tags: react-native

I am working on a react native project and I want to connect with firebase ,but when I install firebase its shows that version 8.2.10 is not compatible with the expo package and install 7.9.0. I don't know what to do, please help !

This is the [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wThnF.png) I am facing.

Comment: I want to install firebase version 7.9.0 but can't work for me I try this command yarn add firebase@7.9.0 but still can't work

Comment: Try `npm i -g firebase-tools` and then `expo install firebase`.

Comment: Thank you so much Rohit sir you helped and it's worked always stay blessed